# Is there a way to define a trigger that runs reliably at a datetime specified as a field in the updated/created object?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-functions

#### The question

Is it possible (and if so, how) to make it so when an object's field `x` (that contains a timestamp) is created/updated a specific trigger will be called at the time specified in `x` (probably calling a serverless function)?

#### My Specific context

In my specific instance the object can be seen as a task. I want to make it so when the task is created a serverless function tries to complete the task and if it doesn't succeed it updates the record with the partial results and specifies in a field `x` when the next attempt should happen.

The attempts should not span at a fixed interval. For example, a task may require 10 successive attempts at approximately every 30 seconds, but then it may need to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no way to (re)trigger a Cloud Function on a node after a certain timespan.

The closest you can get is by regularly scheduling a cron job to run on the list of tasks. For more on that, see [this sample in the function-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron), this [blog post by Abe](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html), and this [video where Jen explains them](https://youtu.be/CbE2PzvAMxA).

I admit I never like using this cron-job approach, since you have to query the list to find the items to process. A while ago, I wrote a more efficient solution that runs a priority queue in a node process. My code was a bit messy, so I'm not quite ready to share it, but it wasn't a lot (<100 lines). So if the cron-trigger approach doesn't work for you, I recommend investigating that direction.

Comment: Problem is that I may have from 10 to 9000+ tasks and I'd like for it to be as concurrent as possible. Wouldn't a single cron job be insufficient as the amount of tasks grow?

Comment: Yes. In fact, my priority queue used a single timer to handle any number of tasks the Node process could handle. With a cron job you'll just have to decide on the granularity of your timers, since you have to define how frequently the cron job executes its trigger when you create it.